# Flutter Integration Test: How to wait until element is disappear with specific time out

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am writing a Flutter Integration Test and I'm looking for a code which that allows the automated test to run and proceed after the Login (check step below) finishes automatically.
.....

here are the step involves

1. Enter username and password
2. hit login button
3. then the loading modal will show up for 2 mins // at this step I need to find some code to make sure that the modal is disappeared so that it can proceed to the next step.

It's just like `Wait Until Element Does Not Contain` in [Selenium](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Wait%20Until%20Element%20Does%20Not%20Contain)

here is my code

```
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4));
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();
  
  var textBoxForPhone = find.byKey(const Key('txtbPhone'));
  var textBoxForPass = find.byKey(const Key('txtbPass'));
  var btnLogin = find.byKey(const Key('btnLogin'));

  var syncMasterModal = find.byKey(const Key('syncMasterModal'));

// Input Username
  await tester.enterText(textBoxForPhone, '9108717875');
// Input Password
  await tester.enterText(textBoxForPass, '12345');
  await tester.testTextInput.receiveAction(TextInputAction.done);
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();
// Tap Login button
  await tester.tap(btnLogin);

//After tapping the login button the loading modal will appear and it takes about 2 minutes to finish this process
// So it is at this step where I need the code to detect whether the loading modal is disappear
```

So could you guys help point me in the right direction?

PS. This is my first time here and English is not my first language so, I'm sorry if my text here is a bit confusing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this is not robotframework specific question and code is not even python. Maybe you should ask around the topics that cater around dart or the library that provides the "tester" implementation.

Answer (score 1):

after -> await tester.tap(btnLogin);
try to add the following lines

await tester.pumpAndSettle();
await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(minutes: 2));  // hardcode it if you are sure about the needed time

expect(find.byType(YourModalWidget), findsNothing);
continue with other code...

Tip: in your tests, when you are transitioning from one screen to the next, after the first pumpAndSettle() add another with a Duration of around 1 second, or 200/500 milliseconds (depends on what you are expecting to load, and tap after that). This will make the transition much smoother and it won't look like it is frozen. if you only add pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 1)), without the first pumpAndSettle() before it, it looks like it's frozen and then the next action in your tests starts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).